# Bind Converter to the parent resource in xaml

Tags: wpf, xaml, data-binding, relativesource

I have a usercontrol1.xaml where I have a resource defined:

```
    <UserControl x:Class="FrameworkDemo.usercontrol1View">
       <UserControl.Resources>
           <local:DemoManger x:Key="demoManager"/>
            <local:DemoManagerConverterx x:Key="demoManagerConverter" Manager="{StaticResource strategyManager}"/>
        </UserControl.Resources>

     <telerik:RadTileView MinimizedItemsPosition="Top">
            <telerik:RadTileViewItem>
               <local:UserControl2View/>
            </telerik:RadTileViewItem>
            <telerik:RadTileViewItem>
                    ........
            </telerik:RadTileViewItem>
     </telerik:RadTileView>
    </UserControl>
```

Then in the user control view 2, I want to have this situation:

```
ss
   <UserControl x:Class="FrameworkDemo.usercontrol2View">

    <DockPanel>
          <ComboBox MinWidth="270" Margin="0,0,5,5"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Demos, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DemoManager}}}"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentStrategy, Converter={ ????}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding CanRefreshExecutionList, ElementName=Instance}"
                    DropDownOpened="StrategyComboBox_DropDownOpened">
    </DockPanel>
    </UserControl>
```

I was able to link to the parent control for the *ItemSource*, but for the converter how can I do it?.  I can not event move the resource definition from control1 to control2. Inside of the *RadTileViewItem* is not possible to add another resource. Exactly in *usercontrol1View* I have a *tabcontrol* inside the *RadTileViewItem* and inside the *tabiteam* i have inlcluded the *UserControl2View*.

How can I link to the parent resource for the covnerter?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand. Why don't you declare a resource dictionary for the second control with a new instance of your converter ?

Comment: Is it the only solution? Define a directory just for the converter thought a bad solution.

Comment: What do you call 'a new directory' ? You mean a new instance ? There is absolutely no problem to do that. You can even bind to a singleton instance too...

Answer (score 1):

> How can I link to the parent resource for the covnerter?

You can't. If you need to use the same converter in both `UserControls`, you have defined the resource in the wrong place actually.

You could either move it to your `App.xaml` file:

```
<Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApp1"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
    <Application.Resources>
        ...
        <local:DemoManagerConverterx x:Key="demoManagerConverter" Manager="{StaticResource strategyManager}"/>
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then you will be able to reference it across your entire application. The other option would be to define another resource of the same type in `UserControl2`:

```
<DockPanel>
    <DockPanel.Resources>
        <local:DemoManagerConverterx x:Key="demoManagerConverter" Manager="{StaticResource strategyManager}"/>
    </DockPanel.Resources>
    <ComboBox MinWidth="270" Margin="0,0,5,5"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Demos, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DemoManager}}}"
                    SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentStrategy, Converter={StaticResource demoManagerConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding CanRefreshExecutionList, ElementName=Instance}"
                    DropDownOpened="StrategyComboBox_DropDownOpened" />
</DockPanel>
```

But you can't reference a resource that is defined in a parent element using bindings.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you wanted bind converter object to the binding's `Converter` property.
You can't bind to the binding's `Converter` property since it is not a ´DependencyProperty´. You can acces a resource object and bind it e.g. to the ´Tag´, but it doesn't solve your problem:

```
<ComboBox MinWidth="270" Margin="0,0,5,5"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Demos, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type local:DemoManager}}}"
        SelectedValue="{Binding Path=CurrentStrategy, Converter={ ????}, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Tag="{Binding Path='Resources[demoManagerConverter]', RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type localFrameworkDemo:usercontrol1View}}}"
        IsEnabled="{Binding CanRefreshExecutionList, ElementName=Instance}"
        DropDownOpened="StrategyComboBox_DropDownOpened">
```

If object is nested, you could just set(not bind) the Converter to the resource object:

```
Converter = {StaticResource demoManagerConverter}
```

Comment: It is not able to find the demoManagerConverter